# Restricting application in google play device having resolution below 480x800px

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

i have developed a hybrid application using phonegap for android phones and tablets. My requirement is to allow our application to be listed in the google play for the device having the resolution more than 480px x 640px .

how can we restrict phones & tablets using android manifest attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My requirement is to allow our application to be listed in the google play for the device having the resolution more than 480px x 640px .

That's not an especially sensible requirement as literally stated.

> how can we restrict phones & tablets using android manifest attributes?

You cannot use manifest attributes to restrict to certain pixel values. At most, you can require certain general size buckets, like `small` and `normal`, as is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `supports-screens` markup, which allows you to specify which screen densities your app supports, and whether or not you allow the OS to automatically scale it.

More information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Specifically:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
              android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
              android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
              android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
              android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
              android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

Comment: thanks. i tried the same. its taking it in dp not pixels. how can we convert it to pixels?

Comment: @yokka: Well, `dp` in Android maps to `px` in CSS. If you truly mean hardware pixels, there is no means to do that. Moreover, the `requiresSmallestWidthDp` and so forth are not used for filtering on the Play Store.